# How to write sexual/romantic scenes?

Tags: fiction, style, creative-writing, technique, characters

Yeah, I just decided today to write a Porn/Erotic Book. Seems writing ebooks is a quick way to make a couple of bucks and rise up the ladder these days. But, the problem is I don't know how to write a romantic/erotic scenes. Also, I still haven't had any relationships or dated anyone or had sex with anyone, so that's again a problem for me if I wish to write a platonic or romantic relationship for my main character. So, any suggestions on how to write them?

My main character's name is Puss Conan. The basic Idea of my story is that Puss Conan is a Room Attendant/Room Keeper aboard the *SS Paradise* which is space carrier on it's way to the Andromeda Galaxy from the Solar System, Mars. It follows Puss Conan and his sexual encounters with various Human Females and aliens aboard the ship. Also, Puss Conan will have various non sexual adventures later on.

Comment: I realize that "You should try to get some sexual experience" is not helpful advice, but sometimes people write about tabs and slots and acts and recovery time and it's painfully obvious that the writer has never been involved in that physical act. So at the very least try to find a beta reader/editor who has experience with the act(s) in question and can tell you if you're being realistic. Nothing breaks an erotic spell like realizing "but you can't physically DO that!" or "WOW, that would really hurt."

Comment: I'm afraid this is extremely broad, and I don't think it's answerable in its present form. We do practical Q&A, and you're basically looking for a 101 course for a whole genre. I need to close this, but if you have specific questions, we'd love to have them.

Comment: In the meantime, very basic advice that I think will help: (A) Look up existing books and blogs and websites devoted to your chosen genre. That's basically what you're looking for here. (B) _Read_ books in the genre; it'll give you a sense of what you like, what works, what interests you. (C) *Write*, even if it's not great the first time or two (or ten). You'll learn _so_ much more by trying to write and dealing with concrete problems, than by trying to absorb a huge amount of knowledge and experience before you first set pen to paper. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Read a few dozen of them. Whenever you read one you like, study the romantic/erotic scenes that were particularly effective for you. Make notes about how you felt as you were reading, and what the writer did in the text that made you feel that way.